# Can I change the Visual Studio text editor's cursor?

Tags: visual-studio

The tiny text entry cursor in the Visual Studio 2005's editor is driving me nuts.  I'd ideally like to be able to highlight (say in yellow) the entire line that I'm currently on, but I'll settle for just making the cursor bigger and/or a different colour.  Any help gratefully received!

Comment: For information, it isn't a cursor (that's the mouse), it is referred to as a Caret when you're talking about the keyboard input position.

Answer (score 3):

[CodeKana](http://www.codekana.com/) allows you to highlight the current line among other nice features. AFAIK Visual Studio has no built-in support for highlighting or otherwise making the current line obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Under Control Panel, Personalization, Choose Mouse Pointers, try different color schemes/pointers for the Text Select cursor, "Windows Inverted (system scheme)" seems to work very well for me.

I found this solution here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/3b131a04-9a51-42c9-b69e-73e6e70c15a7